# Coloring multiple elements with a single CSS declaration

Tags: html, css

I'm new to web development in general and I am stil just a novice in HTML and CSS.

I am currently trying to minimize the number of declarations in my stylesheet to clean it up, but I have come across something I need help with.

Anyway, here is the code I'm asking about:

```
#div1,
#div2,
#div3 {
    width: 100px; height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #f00; 
    background-color: #0f0; 
    float: left; margin: auto 5px auto;
    position: relative; left: 10px; top: 10px;
}
```

Here, each div has a green background color. What I'm trying to do is set a different color for each div in a single declaration.

Is this possible?

Thanks. Appreciate any and all help.

Comment: If clean organized stylesheets is your thing, I would suggest checking out [SASS.] (http://sass-lang.com/) It is designed to minimize the number of declarations in your code and support scalability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest way to style these elements would be to put a common class on them, and only style the individual divs for their differences (the color).

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  float: left;
  margin: auto 5px auto;
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
#div1 {
  background-color: #0f0;
}
#div2 {
  background-color: #0ff;
}
#div3 {
  background-color: #ff0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="div1"></div>
<div class="box" id="div2"></div>
<div class="box" id="div3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in css code

```
#box{
 width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  float: left;
  margin: auto 5px auto;
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

in html code

```
<div id="box" style="background:green"> </div>
<div id="box" style="background:red"> </div>
<div id="box" style="background:blue"> </div>
```

Comment: Having more than one element with the same ID is not valid HTML.

Comment: if all elements are div is a valid, ID don't works with different tags

Comment: Not sure I understand. IDs are not to be repeated on a page, you can only have one `#box` if you want valid HTML. Read more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page

Comment: i think this is a valid ! but if you don't like it, change it to class, what's a problem? :))

Comment: It's not a matter of opinion - class would be valid, but ID is not. Just trying to point out an error. Here's the relevant W3C spec page: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H93.html